# $\mu^*$-measurable sets form a $\sigma$-algebra on which $\mu^*$ is a measure.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing

Define the following:

Let $(X,\mathcal S)$ be a measurable space and $\mu:\mathcal S\to [0,\infty]$ be a function such that $\mu(\phi)=0$ and $\mu$ is countably additive.Then $\mu$ is called a measure on $(X,\mathcal S)$.

Define an outer measure on $X$ to be a function $\mu^*:2^X\to [0,\infty]$ such that $\mu^*(\phi)=0$ and $\mu^*(A)\leq \mu^*(B)$ for $A\subset B$ and $\mu^*$ is countably subadditive.

Now define the following:

A set $A\subset X$ is called $\mu^*$-measurable if $\mu^*(B)=\mu^*(B\cap A)+\mu^*(B\cap A^c)$ for each set $B$ in $X$.

With the above definitions I want to show the following:

The set $M_{\mu^*}$ of all $\mu^*$-measurable functions is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu^*$ is a measure on that $\sigma$-algebra.

I am having problem to show the third condition of $\sigma$-algebra,that of closure under countable union.Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This is Caratheodory's Theorem. [https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiq8_6Pnt72AhXvsFYBHZOOBS8QFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fweb.yonsei.ac.kr%2Fnipi%2FlectureNote%2Fmeasure%2520theory%2520-seo.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3ekEFF3N8ISxR5_9VMToKQ ]

Comment: There are any number of places where you can find a proof. Measure Theory by Halmos has a proof.

Comment: You have to say which step/steps in the proof you don't understand . It is a tremendous waste of resources to reproduce the entire proof here and anyone posting the proof will have to wonder if you would understand that proof either.

Comment: Read 'ring' as algebra and $\sigma$ ring as $\sigma$ algebra.

Comment: You seem to have edited the question to be a complete new one... you should leave it as it is and ask your new question separately.  As it is none of the comments here now make sense.

Comment: @postmortes I have flagged the comments as they are no longer needed.

Comment: If I had asked a new one,then it would not be eligible for bounty......................

Comment: So,I edited this one.

Comment: Why was the bounty important?  I'm pretty certain all you have to do is search for reference-request and measure theory to find a lot of questions this duplicates...

Comment: Please do not edit your post to complete change the question it posed. Instead, post a new question. If your previous question was closed or not well received, consider improving the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the third condition, let's first try to prove:

if $E$ and $F$ are elements of the $\sigma$-algebra then $E \cup F$ is an element of the $\sigma$-algebra.

It means, let's prove:

if $\mu^*(B)=\mu^*(B\cap E)+\mu^*(B\cap E^c)$ and  $\mu^*(B)=\mu^*(B\cap F)+\mu^*(B\cap F^c)$ for every $B\subset X$, then  $\mu^*(B)=\mu^*(B\cap E\cup F)+\mu^*(B\cap (E\cup F)^c)$ for every $B\subset X$.

Since $\mu^*$ is countably subadditive $\mu^*(B)=\mu^*(B\cap X)=\mu^*(B\cap (E\cup F \cup (E\cup F)^c))= \mu^*((B\cap E\cup F) \cup (B\cap (E\cup F)^c))) \le \mu^*(B\cap E\cup F)+\mu^*(B\cap (E\cup F)^c)$

So, to reach the equality, we only need to prove

$\mu^*(B) \ge \mu^*(B\cap E\cup F)+\mu^*(B\cap (E\cup F)^c)$.

---

Lemma (1): For every $B \subset X$ we have:

$\mu^*(B)=\mu^*(B\cap E)+\mu^*(B\cap E^c)$

and, since $F$ is $\mu^*$-measurable, for every $B\cap E$ and $B\cap E^c$ we have:

$\mu^*(B\cap E)=\mu^*(B\cap E \cap F)+\mu^*(B\cap E \cap F^c)$

$\mu^*(B\cap E^c)=\mu^*(B\cap E^c \cap F)+\mu^*(B\cap E^c \cap F^c)$

Therefore,

$\mu^*(B)=\mu^*(B\cap E \cap F)+\mu^*(B\cap E \cap F^c)+\mu^*(B\cap E^c \cap F)+\mu^*(B\cap E^c \cap F^c)$.

---

Since $E \cup F =(E\cap F)) \cup  (E \cap F^c) \cup  (E^c \cap F )$, for every $B$ we have:

$B\cap (E \cup F) =(B\cap (E \cap F)) \cup (B\cap (E \cap F^c)) \cup (B\cap (E^c \cap F) )$.

So by subadditivity, we have:

$\mu^*(B\cap (E \cup F)) \le \mu^*(B\cap (E \cap F)) + \mu^*(B\cap (E \cap F^c)) +\mu^*(B\cap (E^c \cap F) )$.

Let's add $\mu^*(B\cap (E^c \cap F^c))$ to both sides the inequality. The right side becomes $\mu^*(B)$ according to the lemma (1). So we have:

$\mu^*(B\cap (E^c \cap F^c))+\mu^*(B\cap (E \cup F)) \le \mu^*(B)$

or

$\mu^*(B\cap (E \cup F)^c)+\mu^*(B\cap (E \cup F)) \le \mu^*(B)$.

So $\mu^*(B\cap (E \cup F)^c)+\mu^*(B\cap (E \cup F)) = \mu^*(B)$, and $E \cup F$ is $\mu^*$-measurable.

We finished the proof for finite union, now we are going to prove for the countable union.

First, closure under finite union implies the following lemma.

---

Lemma (2): If $E$ and $F$ are disjoint, then

$\mu^*(E \cup F))=\mu^*((E \cup F) \cap E)+ \mu^*((E \cup F) \cap E^c)=\mu^*(E)+\mu^*(F)$

Also, if $E_n$ are disjoint, then, by induction,

$\mu^*(\bigcup_1^n E_i)=\sum_1^n \mu^*(E_i)$

---

Now, consider a sequence of disjoint $\mu^*$-measurable sets {$A_j$}$_1^{\infty}$, and consider $E_n = \bigcup_1^{n}A_j$ and $E = \bigcup_1^{\infty}A_j$.

For every $B\subset X$, we have:

$$\mu^*(B \cap E_n))=\mu^*((B \cap E_n) \cap A_n)+ \mu^*((B \cap E_n) \cap A_n^c)=\mu^*(B \cap A_n)+\mu^*(B \cap E_{n-1})$$

According to the lemma (2), $\mu^*(B \cap E_n)=\sum_1^n \mu^*(B \cap A_j)$, So

$$\mu^*(B)= \mu^*(B \cap E_n))+\mu^*((B \cap E_n^c) \ge \sum_1^n \mu^*(B \cap A_j) +\mu^*((B \cap E_n^c)$$

Now, let $n$ goes to $\infty$,

$$\mu^*(B) \ge \sum_1^{\infty} \mu^*(B \cap A_j) +\mu^*((B \cap E_n^c) \ge \mu^*(\bigcup_1^{\infty} B\cap A_j)+\mu^*(B \cap A_j) = \mu^*(B \cap E)+\mu^*(B \cap E^c) \ge \mu^*(B)$$

It follows that  $\mu^*(B \cap E)+\mu^*(B \cap E^c) = \mu^*(B)$. So, the set $M_{\mu^*}$ is closed under the countable union of disjoint sets and it is a $\sigma$-algebra. Also, in the lemma (2), by letting $n$ goes to $\infty$, we see that $\mu^*$ is a measure.